# Absolute positioning of a div

Tags: html, css, position

```
 .sky-blue
{
    width:1120px;  
    background: skyblue;  
    border:1px solid black;  
    position: absolute;  
    top:70px;  
    bottom:70px;  
    right:70px;  
    left:70px;  
   z-index:-1;  
}
```

Why doesn't this div always leave 70px at the bottom from the page? Until I scroll it appears to be leaving 70px, but once I scroll, I notice more space than 70px between the bottom of the page and div.
Please help me with this.

Comment: you are looking for fixed position

Comment: "why doesn't this div" ...what div?

Answer (score 0):

Change the position value from absolute to fixed:

```
 .sky-blue
{
    width:1120px;  
    background: skyblue;  
    border:1px solid black;
    position: fixed;  
    /*position: absolute;*/  
    top:70px;  
    bottom:70px;  
    right:70px;  
    left:70px;  
   z-index:-1;  
}
```

Absolute positioning positions the element in relation to it's containing box, where as fixed positioning positions the element in relation to the viewport (the browser window).